# What is the certificate in the context of RSA and asymmetric encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I try to implement a asymmetric encription for learning purpose. I learned that a certificate helps to identify the owner of a public key. But how can I implement a certificate? Can you give me an example of a certificate I can use?

I implemented the encryption and decryption, but now i want to use a certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a self signed X.509 certificate using OpenSSL - there are many tutorials online. Certificates have standardized formats and are not specific to Java.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:3072 -sha256 -nodes -keyout privkey.pem -out selfsigned.pem
openssl pkcs8 -in privkey.pem -nocrypt -outform DER -out privkey.p8
openssl x509 -in selfsigned.pem -outform DER -out selfsigned.crt
```

This generates two files for the certificate (which contains the public key) and one for the private key. There is also a PEM encoded private key and certificate, which Java does not directly handle. The private key files are not encrypted or otherwise protected, so use this only for testing purposes.

The certificate is compatible with [`CertificateFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) for `"X.509"`. The private key is compatible with [`KeyFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) with `"RSA"` as algorithm and [`PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html).

Java itself cannot *directly* be used when it comes to generating certificates. You can use Bouncy Castle or even EJBCA if in-code generation is required, but that is quite a steep learning curve.

Comment: After that you could explore Java keystores / trust stores and PKCS#12, then certificate chains, etc. etc. until you know everything about PKI / PKIX - it's quite a bit of knowledge.

Comment: Note `CertificateFactory "X.509"` can read _either_ PEM or DER (so your third command isn't needed), but `KeyFactory "RSA"` only PKCS8-unencrypted DER. Java [`keytool -genkeypair`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html) CAN create keypair and selfsigned cert in a keystore file (which since j9 defaults to PKCS12) and since j7 also `keytool -gencert` creates a child cert under a CA key-and-cert from a CSR. To build an _arbitrary_ cert you do need Bouncy.

Comment: Oh, OK. Never used them actually, we had tons of ways of creating certs, and openssl is present almost anywhere. Might be a good idea to create them in a keystore directly, then you might be able to better protect the private key at least. Unfortunately most of the code relies on Sun / Oracle internal software, missing from the public API.

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is a piece of data that attaches certain additional information to someone's public key, and is digitally signed by a well-known third-party (authority).

The common format for certificates is X.509, encoded in ASN1.

A typical certificate would contain at least a "common name", the subject key fingerprint (a hash of the public key being certified), a validity period and a CA signature of all that.